# DOM manipulation for fullCalendar js

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using [**`fullcalendar`**](https://fullcalendar.io/), a JavaScript event calendar which leverages on jQuery.

I need to edit all day cells of the calendar, adding two verticals lists, both floating left; do I have to achieve that handling events?

Well; I think not.

Is there a simple and effective way to achieve that?

Below is my code illustrating my failed attempt to achieving that:

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({   
    header: {
        left: 'prev',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'next'
    },
    //defaultDate: '2015-02-12',
    monthNames:
        ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
    dayNamesShort:
        ['D', 'L', 'M', 'M','J', 'V', 'S'],     
    editable: false,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        //element.find(".fc-view-month td").after($("<td class=\"fc-day\"></td>").html("Prueba"));
        //element.find("div.fc-event-inner").prepend("<img src='" + event.imageurl +"' width='12' height='12'>");
        //element.find("div.fc-event-inner").prepend("<img src='../img/ico_calen_min_1.png' width='12' height='12' />");
        //element.find("table tbody td").prepend("<img src='../img/ico_calen_min_1.png' width='12' height='12' />");
        //element.find(".fc-title").after($("<span class=\"fc-event-icons\"></span>").html("<ul><li><img src=\"../img/ico_calen_min_1.png\" /></li><li><img src=\"../img/ico_calen_min_1.png\" /></li></ul>"));             
        //element.find(".fc-view-month").after($("td").html("<ul><li><img src=\"../img/ico_calen_min_1.png\" /></li><li><img src=\"../img/ico_calen_min_1.png\" /></li></ul>"));                
        //$("#calendar .fc-view-month td").append("<input type=\"checkbox\">AM<br>");
    }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in pure css using [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Abefore) pseudo and [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) and for example an iconic font like [`fontawesome`](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/).

> The content CSS property is used with the ::before and ::after
>   pseudo-elements to generate content in an element. Objects inserted
>   using the content property are anonymous replaced elements.

Following an example on the month view.

`\A` and `white-space: pre` are needed for line breaking the icons.

Code:

```
.fc-widget-content::before {
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-family:'FontAwesome';
    content:"\f0c9\A\f0ac\A\f09c\A\f257";
    position: absolute;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/dcx5unzd/

UPDATE

To display a column with the numbers you can use the event and style it accordingly like:

```
.fc-event{
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: auto !important;
}
```

Here is a demo of your events:

```
var events_array = [{
    title: '1\n2\n5\n8',
    start: new Date(2015, 9, 20),
}, {
    title: '5\n4\n1\n2',
    start: new Date(2015, 9, 21),
    tip: 'Personal tip 2'
}];
```

the `\n` is fundamental for the newline for the column number.

See:

[image]

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/dcx5unzd/1/

Comment: and if i want, to repeat next to the icons column, the same column, like the image, how would be?, after could put a link in each icon? thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "and if i want, to repeat next to the icons column, the same column" is not the event content?

Comment: In the image, i have a column with icons and next is other column with numbers. How make it?. In this moment, i dont need events, but in the future, if i need a link in the icons, i must  use events?

Comment: and one more thing, the icons must be own images, thanks

Comment: ok, for to create my own icons, i visited: http://www.40defiebre.com/como-convertir-iconos-fuente/, but still i dont know to repeat next to the icons column other column

Comment: Yes, you use an event to set the number column and style it accordingly, check the edit

Comment: the last thing please, i want a unique event in all calendar, the event  array, with one element that to repeat in all calendar.

Comment: You can create an "year" events calendar, it's a bit strange, but it's like: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/dcx5unzd/3/

Comment: Hi @Eladerezador if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.