# Show all event date dots even with missing dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I have FullCalendar plugin it works great 
I read data from Json object by this code

```
 function press1() {
            var employees = {
                events: []
            };
            for (var i in DonationRequests) {
                var item = DonationRequests[i];
                employees.events.push({
                    "title": "collectorID" + item.CollectorID + " ",
                    "start": eval(item.CreateDate.replace(/\/Date\((\d+)\)\//gi, "new Date($1)"))
                });
            }

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
               employees
            );
        }
```

and it looks like 
[image]

In another words 
In my code I show only the data which read from database ,
but I need to make calendar show 4 red circles even it is not found in database, and if it founded an object in the day color it to green

for more explanation :-

Fullcalendar plugin show dots from events , and I fill events from database , but my database contains some dates as `2016-05-31` and `2016-05-17` So calendar will show only those two dates , but I need to show all dates and just color the incoming from database to green

I find this link
 [FullCalendar js - To add code html in all day cells II](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33036175/fullcalendar-js-to-add-code-html-in-all-day-cells-ii)
 but it didn't work for me , any suggestions ?
please help

Comment: Please rephrase your post. It's unclear what are you doing or asking. Also a fiddle will help us to help you

Comment: @EyalAbir what is unclear for you!!, all what I need to show event marks in all days not only the days which comes from database.

Comment: It is not clear what do you have working. The events from the DB shows those dots?

Comment: @EyalAbir 
 
totally Fullcalendar plugin show dots from events , and I fill events from database , but my database contains some dates as `2016-05-31` and `2016-05-17` So calendar will show only those two dates , but I need to show all dates and just color the incoming from database to green , did you get it?

Answer (score 0):

Add Custom event css

```
.fc-event {              
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 12px;
}
```

you may modify as you need

Fidde http://jsfiddle.net/4zfyaovk/7/

Comment: Updated the fiddle to hide the text also

Comment: I need to do this in all days not only specific days

Comment: it will display all events like in rounded shape, just add that css class

Comment: but where does this dots coming from??

Comment: I don't know so, I ask if there is any way to do this?

Comment: so, u want 4 dots in all day cells, but display green only if there is an event ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33036175/fullcalendar-js-to-add-code-html-in-all-day-cells-ii please see this link , it may helps, but it didn't work with me